# Setting up a Horner polynomial in R

Tags: r

I am trying to set up a function in R that computes a polynomial

- P(x) = c1 + c2*x + c3*x^2 + ... + cn-1*x^n-2 + cn*x^n-1

for various values of x and set coefficients c.

Horner's method is to

- Set cn = bn
- For i = n-1, n-1, ..., 2, 1, set bi = bi+1*x + ci
- Return the output

What I have so far:

```html
hornerpoly1 <- function(x, coef, output = tail(coef,n=1), exp = seq_along(coef)-1) {
  for(i in 1:tail(exp,n=1)) {
    (output*x)+head(tail(coef,n=i),n=1)
  }
}
hornerpoly <- function(x, coef) {
  exp<-seq_along(coef)-1
  output<-tail(coef,n=1)
  if(length(coef)<2) {
    stop("Must be more than one coefficient")
  }
  sapply(x, hornerpoly1, coef, output,exp)
}
```

I also need to error check on the length of coef, that's what the if statement is for but I am not struggling with that part. When I try to compute this function for x = 1:3 and coef = c(4,16,-1), I get three NULL statements, and I can't figure out why. Any help on how to better construct this function or remedy the null output is appreciated. Let me know if I can make anything more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

Define a function that takes `x` as the argument at which to evaluate the polynomial, and `coef` as the vector of coefficients in decreasing order of degree. So the vector `coef = c(-1, 16, 4)` corresponds to `P(x) = -x^2 + 16 * x + 4`.

The [Horner algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) is implemented in the following function:

```
f.horner <- function(x, coef) {
    n <- length(coef);
    b <- rep(0, n);
    b[n] <- coef[n];
    while (n > 0) {
        n <- n - 1;
        b[n] <- coef[n] + b[n + 1] * x;
    }
    return(b[1]);
}
```

We evaluate the polynomial at `x = 1:3` for `coef = c(-1, 16, 4)`:

```
sapply(1:3, f.horner, c(-1, 16, 4))
#[1] 19 47 83
```

Some final comments:

1. Note that the check on the length of `coef` is realised in the statement `while (n > 0) {...}`, i.e. we go through the coefficients starting from the last and stop when we reach the first coefficient.
2. You don't need to save the intermediate `b` values as a vector in the function. This is purely for (my) educational/trouble-shooting purposes. It's easy to rewrite the code to store `b`s last value, and then update `b` every iteration. You could then also vectorise `f.horner` to take a vector of `x` values instead of only a scalar.

Comment: Wow I don't think I ever could've gotten this, something about programming just doesn't click with me, but this is exactly what I needed. Thanks for taking the time. I'd upvote if I could.